# Find cell with same value in another worksheet, and sum it only if another cell has a value

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a report that is generated in Sheets which contains an employee's name, but not his/her Transaction status. Not every employee will be on this worksheet on any given day.

In a 2nd worksheet I have a list of all employees' names,transaction and their status.

I want a formula in the first worksheet that looks for the same value (the employee name) on the 2nd workbook and then **Sums**the all the money under his\her name(Amount transfered) **IF** the transaction has been made of the cell 4 rows to the LEFT of that (transaction status) on the first workbook. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to  Stack Overflow. Please include links to similar questions on this site. Reference [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the SUMIF function:

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en

You could do something like this:

```
=if(A2="foo",sumif(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5,B2,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$5))
```

where:

```
a2 = status for this client in the first sheet
sheet2!$a$2:$a$5 = list of all names in second sheet
b2 = name of this client in first sheet
sheet2:$b$2:$b$5 = corresponding transaction amount for each name in sheet2!$a$2:$a$5
```

Is this close to what you were looking for?

Comment: Please describe how the referred function could be used on the scenario described in the question.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a poorly phrased question, so can't quite understand exactly what the author is looking for. Data sample would've been helpful..

Comment: This is almost a link only answer, so it could attract downvotes. If you think  that the question was poorly phrase consider to ask the OP to fix that.

Comment: Thanks. Would be happy to comment, but don't have enough points yet

Comment: Ups. Sorry, I forgot that commenting on any post requires some reputation level.

Comment: OK let me make my self clearer:)  I get a report from an insurance company containing my clients status with their transaction every day. So in the first worksheet i have the name of the client with the amount of money he transfered, And in my 2nd worksheet i copy\paste the data recieved in the insurance report including their  name, transaction status and the amount recieved(more than 1 transaction per client - with different status)... what I'm trying to do here is to generate an easy tool for extracting the data from their report, sum it and put it in the

Comment: It worked! but when i tried to apply it on the rest of the cells in the first sheet by draging down the working cell down - the value returned was FALSE

Comment: Yes, sorry you have to use $ symbol to anchor the Sheet2 range. Please see latest edit thanks